# Magento Short Description Bug

Tags: magento, view, short

i got a problem with magento.
if i click on a product in grid view, the short description is missing and the product name is below the product picture (not the case for list view), but as soon i swap to list view AND swap back to grid view, everything is fine?! the product name is above the picture and the descrption is shown.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access this file:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

**Note**: Remember to copy to your template

It is divided into 2 parts list and grid, understand and modify the code to fix the name or short description

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but this did not solve my problem. This code manages everything after i changed the view to something else (that part works fine). When i choose a product from the product list, then it's buggy. Where do i find those code parts?